# Magento: Category WYSIWYG Editor Image not displaying on custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg, category-description

I am getting category description on 2columns-left.phtml by following code:

[image: display category description]

Text are showing but media wysiwyg images not showing on frontend.

I am getting images in WYSIWYG Editor like:

[image: <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category_quality_image/em1.jpg"}}" />]

How to display images on frontend of category description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your code with

```
<?php 
$_description = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription();
echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
$_cmsHelper = Mage::helper('cms');
$_process = $_cmsHelper->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
echo $_process->filter($category_description);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<?php echo '<img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/category_quality_image/em1.jpg"}}" />' ?>
```